# Access RadControl using Javascript

Tags: javascript, telerik, firebug, browser-automation

I need to automate some website and there are a few RadControls (RadCombobox, RadDatePicker, RadTimePicker).
I'm using Webbrowser component in C# WinForms.

To formulate this question more widely and make it more common I will ask it this way:

Assume you're in Console of Firebug.. What commands I should run to select some item from RadCombobox and set date into RadDatePicker?

I know that these telerik controls have their own API and methods such as set_date and set_time.
But how I can obtain this object?

I could access combobox via DOM elements:
        `window.frames[0].document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rcbCtrl1').click()`

But it doesn't allow me to use controls' methods.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it.

Need to refer RadControl object via $find and then use control's own API like that:
$find('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rcbCtrl1').set_value()

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$find("<%= rcbCtrl1.ClientID %>")
```

or

```
 $find("<%# rcbCtrl1.ClientID %>")
```